# SQL Query to not display null values

Tags: mysql, null

I have managed to hack an SQL Query together and it was working until I realised some members in the database have null names due to the plugin we are using removes non-ascii names. I am displaying these stats on my page and having someone with no name doesn't work too well. I know how to not display NULL when using the WHERE clause but i'm not too sure when no WHERE clause is used.

What I have so far -

```
SELECT player_stats.player_name, COUNT(player_kill.killer) 
FROM player_stats 
LEFT JOIN player_kill ON player_stats.player_id = player_kill.killer  
GROUP BY player_stats.player_name 
HAVING COUNT(player_kill.killer) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(player_kill.killer) DESC;
```

Comment: After the LEFT JOIN; before the GROUP BY.

Comment: @user3741598 I've added WHERE player_stats.player_name IS NOT NULL but it's still showing NULL values.

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. Then you won't get any rows with no match, and the count will always be `> 1`.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried INNER JOIN but for some odd reason it's still returning null.

Comment: @NathanK My comment has nothing to do with the null player name.

Comment: Are you sure the player name is null, and not an empty string?

Comment: @Barmar Ahhhhhh! I've just realised NULL shows as (NULL) so I am guessing it is an empty string.

Comment: @Barmar You are the man! I have compared it against an empty string and this solved the issue ;)

Comment: @NathanK - as Barmar stated - NULL is NULL, not "" (empty). If that's the case then you need to do an UPDATE and change all rows with empty to NULL (or test for both - better to clean up the issue IMHO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause goes between all the `JOIN` clauses and `GROUP BY`. If `WHERE player_name IS NOT NULL` isn't working, the names are probably empty strings, not `NULL`, so you need to check for that as well.

```
SELECT s.player_name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM player_stats AS s
INNER JOIN player_kill AS k ON s.player_id = k.killer  
WHERE s.player_name IS NOT NULL AND s.player_name != ''
GROUP BY s.player_name 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Also, if you don't want to get 0 counts, use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your query to much you can replace the players name by checking if it's null.

```
SELECT ISNULL(s.player_name, "RandomPlayer"), COUNT(*) AS count
FROM player_stats AS s
INNER JOIN player_kill AS k ON s.player_id = k.killer  
WHERE s.player_name IS NOT NULL AND s.player_name != ''
GROUP BY s.player_name 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx